# $ in DataFrame API

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Question about the new DataFrame API in Spark 1.3.

In some example in the documentation there is df.groupBy($"something").

What is the meaning of $ here. Is it specific to Spark or a general Scala thing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Spark thing. Notice that `groupBy` takes a variable number of `Column`s, so included in its `implicits` object is a [`StringToColumn`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$implicits$$StringToColumn) class which converts a `String` to a `Column` via this `$` operator.

The Scala way to do it would be to use a backtick, however they probably went with the `$` as it is more easily used in Java